# Django collectstatic Permission denied with docker-compose

Tags: django, docker

I'm making a Django app and I'm using Docker por production deployment, the application almost runs fine on the VPS(Ubuntu 20.04) except that when I try to run collectstatic with this command:

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml exec web python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
```

Always throws this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/app/web/staticfiles/img/app_logo.png'
```

This is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: "postgres:13.2-alpine"
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432" # HOST:CONTAINER
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    container_name: web
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/production/Dockerfile
    environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: MyApp.app_settings.production
    command: gunicorn MyApp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    expose:
      - "8000"
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    volumes:
      - .:/app # Enable code reload
      - ./run/static:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - ./run/media:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    build: docker/production/nginx
    volumes:
      - ./run/static:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - ./run/media:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - web
```

and this is my Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
#RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app
RUN adduser --system --group app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/staticfiles
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/mediafiles
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# Own home directory
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
#RUN apk update && apk add libpq
#COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
#COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
#RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

COPY ./requirements.txt $APP_HOME
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get update
# Install netcat
RUN apt install -y netcat
# Install wkhtml2pdf
RUN wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y -q ./wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb

# copy entrypoint-prod.sh
COPY ./docker/prod/ep.prod.sh $APP_HOME

# execution permissions
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/home/app/web/ep.prod.sh"]

# copy project
#COPY . $APP_HOME
COPY --chown=app:app . $APP_HOME


# chown all the files to the app user
#RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app

# run entrypoint.prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/ep.prod.sh"]
```

I believe that my Dockerfile should have something wrong, but I don't know exactly what. Anyone can help me?

**Edit:**
With the answer below, they suggest to run it this way and works fine:

```
docker exec -it -u 0 [CONTAINER_NAME] python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
```

Also I found this solution, but I believe that this is not safe, any other suggestion?

```
chmod a+rwx -R run/
```

I followed this tutorial: https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/

Comment: when you exec your command this run as your app user so that is why you faced this error.

Answer (score 0):

You must add `-u 0` to your command for run as root user:

```
docker exec -it -u 0 [CONTAINER_NAME] python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm following this guide: https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/ and runs collectstatic without sudo, like this:  docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml exec web python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear

Comment: the ```sudo``` command  depends on your docker-compose installation on you server. but for run you command as root permission you must ```exec``` container with ```-u 0``` flag.

Comment: Thanks, but a question, with this line: RUN chown -R app:app $HOME i'm owning all files and directories from $HOME, then if the collectstatic command runs as app user, shouldn't be permission denied because i'm owning all the files and directories previously copied?

Comment: try dive into to your container and run ```ls -la``` on your directories and files.

Comment: The only directories that are not owned by app user are ep.prod.sh, and /staticfiles and /mediafiles, this are the only owned by root, why is that?

Comment: I see your docker file has few faults. maybe if you move ```RUN chown -R app:app $HOME``` to end file (before change user), your problem will resolve.

Comment: pls if my answer is correct mark it as useful. tnx.

Comment: Can you tell me which faults? Can you add them on the answer please? Also tried to move the RUN chown -R app:app $HOME  to end of file, but still folder is owned by root

Answer (score 0):

I have been stuck for a few hours on this issue. After making sure all the static directory and Django config are in place and proper privileges via shell onto the container. I was with no success.

After searching for a few hours, came to this  [document](https://pawamoy.github.io/posts/docker-compose-django-postgres-nginx/#static-files-collecting-storing-and-serving)
 which says you need to manually `collect static` after demonizing the container.

Commands:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
docker-compose exec <your-web-service> python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear
```

The answer may long be solved but reference to future users, who would be in the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. To avoid docker-compose exec, you can collect the static files while you're the root user in the DOCKERFILE. The DOCKERFILE should look like :

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
#RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app
RUN adduser --system --group app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/staticfiles
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/mediafiles
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# Own home directory
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
#RUN apk update && apk add libpq
#COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
#COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
#RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

COPY ./requirements.txt $APP_HOME
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get update
# Install netcat
RUN apt install -y netcat
# Install wkhtml2pdf
RUN wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y -q ./wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb

# copy entrypoint-prod.sh
COPY ./docker/prod/ep.prod.sh $APP_HOME

# execution permissions
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/home/app/web/ep.prod.sh"]

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME # <<<----- ADDED LINE
RUN python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput # <<<----- ADDED LINE


# chown all the files to the app user
#RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app

# run entrypoint.prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/ep.prod.sh"]
```